# Sum first n non-blank values in a column in date order and stop at row X

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

There are three columns in a document:

- column A contains Names of people,
- column B contains Dates and
- column C contains Numbers/Values. Column C may contain BLANK rows.

There is a row for each day for each person for e.g. the past two years so over 600 rows per person. I need to do the following:

1. Make sure that values are taken in date order
2. Per person
3. Pick up the first 52 non blank values from column B and sum them
4. But stop when you reach row 120 (even if this means that you don't get to sum 52 values)
5. Divide by the count of the number of non-blank values that you found before reaching row 120

For example:

- We look at Joe and he has 52 non-blank values in column C before day 120 so we sum these 52 values and divide the sum by 52.
- We look at Jane who has 30 non-blank values in column C before day 120 so we sum these 30 values and divide this sum by 30.

Any help hugely appreciated. I've been mind boggling with this for hours and can't figure it out...

Many thanks in advance !

N.

Comment: Will there ever be *more* than 52 values before row 120?

Comment: Will the values in `Column C` ever be 0?

Comment: Also unclear how the sort order will impact this. Would you only sort by date? Or by name and then date? If the position here matters then the sorting you decide to use also matters

Comment: It looks like a homework question, which we can certainly help with but only if you show your code and ask specific questions on how to solve a specific problem.

Comment: Which Excel-Version do you use?

Comment: @BigBen - Yes, there may be more than 52 values before row 120;

Comment: @urdearboy, no, just blank. They can be 0 if this is easier to implement. The sort would be by name and date;

Comment: @PeterT - I don't have any code at the moment. There is a piece of development that I want us to test with Excel to make sure it's correct. It would be good to "automate" it to help the team rather than do it manually;

Comment: @Chris - version 2016. Thanks all for your questions.

Comment: @Nena I‘m happy with you :). Maybe you can vote the answer.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that your excel version supports SUMIFS() AND COUNTIFS(), if yes here is a solution with two "helper"-columns

[image]

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick - thank you so much Chris !!